# Find most frequent combination of numbers in a set

Tags: algorithm, search, set, combinations

This question is related to the following questions:

> [How to find most frequent combinations of numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698519/how-can-i-find-most-frequent-combinations-of-numbers-in-a-list)
>
> [Most frequently occurring combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187745/most-commonly-occuring-combination)

My problem is:

Scenario:
I have a set of `numbers`, `EACH COMBINATION IS UNIQUE` in this set and each number in the combination appears only once:

Goal:
Find frequency of appears of combination (size of 2) in this set.

Example:

The frequency threshold is 2.

Set = {1,12,13,134,135,235,2345,12345}

The frequency of degree of 2 combination is(show all combinations that appears more than 2 times):

> 13 - appear 4 times
>
> 14 - appear 3 times
>
> 23 - appear 3 times
>
> 12 - appear 2 times
>
> ...

The time complexity of exhaustive searching for all possible combinations grow exponentially.

Can any one help me to think a algorithm that can solve this problem faster? (hash table, XOR, tree search....)

Thank you

PS.
Don't worry about the space complexity

Solution and conclusion:

`templatetypedef`'s answer is good for substring' length more than 3

If substring's length is 2, `btilly`'s answer is straight forward and easy to implement (also have a good performance on time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pseudo-code whose running time should be `O(n * m * m)` where `n` is the size of the set, and `m` is the size of the things in that set:

```
let counts be a hash mapping a pair of characters to a count
foreach number N in list:
    foreach pair P of characters in N:
        if exists counts[P]:
            counts[P] = counts[P] + 1
        else:
            counts[P] = 1
 let final be an array of (pair, count)
 foreach P in keys of counts:
     if 1 < counts[P]:
         add (P, counts[P]) to final
 sort final according to the counts
 output final
```

@templatetypedef's answer is going to eventually be more efficient if you're looking for combinations of 3, 4, etc characters.  But this should be fine for the stated problem.

Comment: Thank you @btilly, your solution is working very well with length of 2

Answer (score 1):

You can view this problem as a string problem: given a collection of strings, return all substrings of the collection that appear at least k times. Fortunately, there's a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem That uses generalized suffix trees.

Start by constructing a generalized suffix tree for the string representations of your numbers, which takes time linear in the number of digits across all numbers. Then, do a DFS and annotate each node with the number of leaf nodes in its subtree (equivalently, the number of times the string represented by the node appears in the input set), and in the course of doing so output each string discovered this way to appear at least k times. The runtime for this operation is O(d + z), where d is the number of total digits in the input and z is the total number of digits produced as output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @templatetypedef, thank you for you clever answer, I think I understand what you mean, but I don't know how to build the tree using the components in the set. can you give me a brief example? like {1,12,13,23} , what do i need to build the tree? The union of each element or build suffix tree for each element?... Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesChow Are you familiar with suffix trees and generalized suffix trees?

Comment: Hi @templatetypedef, for my understanding, the algorithm is working like this: 1 step. Build the tree. 2nd step. Use each combination to perform a DFS search?

Comment: @CharlesChow No worries! I'd recommend doing a quick Google search to learn more about them, since they're pretty versatile and make it a lot easier to solve problems like these. I doubt I could give a short explanation.

Comment: Hi @templatetypedef, I know how to build the tree, but I don't understand which string should I use to build the tree? For example set = {1,12,13,23} should I use string "1121323" to build the tree? Or should I build a forest that each tree is a element in this set?

Comment: @CharlesChow You would insert endmarkers between each string, such as 1$12$13$23$, then eliminate extraneous branches from the resulting tree.

Comment: Hi @templatetypedef, I got it! Sorry one more question... what branch is considered as extraneous branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60473/discussion-between-charles-chow-and-templatetypedef).